# Vanishing cycles and relative homology of I_n fiber

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, elliptic-surfaces

Suppose $\pi: X \rightarrow D$ is a smooth elliptic fibration with a section over the closed disk without multiple fibers, such that all special fibers are in the interior of $D$. The boundary $\partial X$ is then a torus-bundle over $S^1 \cong \partial D$.
I would like to know the kernel of the map $i_*: H_1(\partial X; \mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow H_1(X; \mathbb{Z})$ that arises in the long exact sequence of relative homology groups $H_\bullet(X, \partial X; \mathbb{Z})$. To get started, I'm looking at the case where the only special fiber of $\pi$ is an $I_n$ fiber.

From the known monodromy $f \in SL(2, \mathbb{Z})$ of an $I_n$ fiber, a Mayer-Vietoris sequence yields $H_1(\partial X, \mathbb{Z}) = \langle \partial\sigma \rangle \oplus \langle \alpha \rangle \oplus \langle \beta \rangle \cong \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_n$. Here, $\sigma$ is the section of $\pi$, whose boundary gives a 1-cycle in $\partial X$; $\alpha$ and $\beta$ form a sympletic basis of the smooth torus fiber, such that the monodromy acts as $f(\alpha) = \alpha + n \beta$, and $f(\beta) = \beta$.

Now, the map $i_* H_1(\partial X) \rightarrow H_1(X)$ is induced by the natural inclusion $\partial X \hookrightarrow X$. So I need to know which of the 1-cycles on $\partial X$ are trivial in $X$. This is fairly obvious for $\partial \sigma$. As for the $\alpha$ and $\beta$ cycles, I would have said naively that the those that sit in $ker(i_*)$ are precisely the vanishing cycles of the $I_n$ fiber, since moving them along a vanishing path from $\partial D$ to the special fiber gives a 2-chain whose boundary sits entirely in $\partial X$. Is this intuition accurate? If yes, then I'm further not sure if the vanishing cycles relevant for this "deformation" is generated by $\beta$, or $n\beta$.

Comment: I think your intuition is accurate, and the vanishing cycles are generated by $\beta$, since the vanishing cycle actually appears as a simple closed curve in the torus and $n\beta$ is not represented by a simple closed curve. I will try to write an answer proving this rigorously if I have time...